# jQuery ajax search

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to implement a window below a searchbar, which displays search results name + their image. At the moment a summy object with the info would be enough. Something like this maybe?

`data: "{one : 'test',two: 'test2' }"`

I have some basic jquery knowlegde, but dont really know where to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) plugin which is nice and easy to setup, just pass `data` as your data argument

Comment: Followup question, if i want more than one value from each result. Can i make it return a soruce with an associative array or something similar. If i want some text and a link for example. Thanks

Comment: Yup, just see the 'Custom Data and display' example in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for autocomplete.  Look up the jQuery autocomplete widget and start from there.